# Link error with Xcode 7 beta, address sanitization and CocoaPods + adMob

Tags: xcode, admob, cocoapods, xcode7, address-sanitizer

I successfully converted an iOS project to Xcode 7 beta + Swift 2 (it runs and the tests work).

However, when I turn on the new Address Sanitizer (option+run -> run -> Diagnostics -> Enable Address Sanitizer, I get the following message from the linker:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___asan_init_v5", referenced from:
  _asan.module_ctor in libPods.a(Pods-dummy.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Seems to reference to CocoaPods which I use for the adMob pod.
I updated CocoaPods itself to the latest version and I updated the adMob Pod to the latest version.

Any hints how to get Address Sanitizer to work together with CocoaPods or the AdMob CocoaPod whichever causes this?

Comment: I also sent a mail to AdMob support.

Comment: Successfully installed cocoapods-0.37.2

Comment: Versions: Successfully installed cocoapods-0.37.2; Using Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (7.3.1)

Comment: Reproduced with XCode 7 beta 3 as expected

Comment: I've seen this with other frameworks (ex: ArcGIS). Haven't found a solution either.

Comment: I have the same problem myself, in this case with the [Box iOS SDK](https://cocoapods.org/pods/box-ios-sdk) and [SWTableViewCell](https://cocoapods.org/pods/SWTableViewCell). The linker is missing symbols with names like `__asan_init`, obviously for address sanitizer at too many call sites to list. I’d guess the pods are rebuilding for AS, but aren’t bringing it in for linkage. Advice, before I dig into the pods’ build configurations?